# Is it dead bodies?

Tags: questions

In movie *The Visit 2015* the boy ask himself, **"Is it dead bodies?"**

Is the question correct? Shouldn't be, **"Are they dead bodies?"**
or, **"Is it dead body?"**

Comment: See [Agreement in “{Singular Noun} Is/Are {Plural Noun}”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766) on ELU. The verb only has to agree in number with the subject ("it", in the sentence you are asking about) and the complement/predicate noun doesn't have to have the same grammatical number as the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can be correct grammar to say "is it dead bodies". For example, in the rhetorical "Is it dead bodies they will find, or the answer to their question?". In this case, 'answer' is singular and the question is really "What is it that they will find?"

Similarly, "What am I looking at? Is it dead bodies?"

On the other hand, "What are those shapes? Is it dead bodies?" would be wrong because 'shapes' is plural. So it depends on the context.